# Bitmap.UriSource is not getting set

Tags: c#, wpf, uri

**This Works:**
Sending `Uri` directly as a parameter to the constructor sets the `UriSource` of the object `photo`.

```
BitmapImage photo = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/EmptyImage.jpg"));
```

[image]

**Doesn't Work:**

But setting the `UriSource` property keeps the `UriSource` as null

```
BitmapImage photo = new BitmapImage();
photo.UriSource = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/EmptyImage.jpg");
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.urisource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> BitmapImage.UriSource must be in a BeginInit/EndInit block.

So you need to set it this way:

```
BitmapImage photo = new BitmapImage();
photo.BeginInit();
photo.UriSource = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/EmptyImage.jpg");
photo.EndInit();
```

Comment: Gosh! Why didn't I read that :P. Ideally it should throw an exception, rather it just ignores it.